# How to prevent EditText filling screen when in horizontal orientation

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, orientation, maximize

I have this `EditText` :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#ababab"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
```

I have two `main.xml` layouts, one for `vertical` and one for `horizontal`, they are in the correct directories to automatically be picked up. The problem I am facing however is whenever the screen rotates horizontally the `EditText` maximises and has a button "**[Next]**" showing on the right of it.

How can I avoid this and show the `EditText` the same way it does in Portrait?

I tested using Android 4.4

Comment: Edit text width property is set to match_parent so it will always strech to get width of its container try set it fixed width, OR you can wrap it in some kind of container ex linear layout and use weights so then it will always be proportionally wide regardless orientation

Comment: Add the following attribute to the EditText element: `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `flagNoExtractUi` imeOption to your `EditText`. Add this below property in xml.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
    android:layout_width="0" <!-- 0dp -->
    android:layout_weight="3" <!-- percentage-->
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#ababab"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0" <!-- 0dp -->
        android:layout_weight="5" <!-- percentage-->
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>
```